# Server 14.04 on a laptop?

Tags: 14.04, server, power-management, battery

I have a Dell E6320 that I recently installed Ubuntu Server on after a motherboard failure.  However, since installing Ubuntu, I noticed that the battery refuses to charge. I know the battery is good, and for the short time Windows was installed after the motherboard replacement, it would hold a charge.

What can I check?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing non-server kernel first.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

and reboot.

Comment: No dice. I ended up having to completely re-image it AGAIN, but this time I straight up put desktop on it with the same results. I'm wondering if there is an ACPI setting on the mobo that I am missing.